# Web API 2 authorize via Google

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I have built a simple web api that I need to authorize using google. I've seen VS templates that come with all the authentication scaffolding for external services. But I want to implement this from scratch in an empty web api project. The behaviour I am looking for is that when an authorize method of my API is called, the user is auto redirected to google login. Once he signs in, he should be automatically returned to my web api's restricted method and be able to execute it. What steps do I need to do (1) in my code, (2) on Google side. Also is auto redirect to and back from google or possible? How can I test this on postman.

Update:

I am following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services#MICROSOFT

I created a Single Page App, as shown. I haven't modified code at all. I went to console.developers.google.com/apis and created a new Credential and plugged that into the Startup.Auth.cs as shown in the microsoft article. When I run the app, I see the google login button. I resolved the SSL issues by installing the certificate in IE. Then, when I click the google login button, I do get redirect, however, I immediately get this error in my code:

Unhandled exception at line 218, column 177 in ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/1508537125-aspen_refresh_approval_page_lib.js

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'botguard' is undefined

Consequently I also get presented by the Google Request for Permission screen, where I am able to Deny or Allow. If I Allow it, it just returns to the same login screen of the app, and I am not logged in.

Comment: This question is way to broad.  Please come back after you have done some research if you have any problems  I would recommend starting here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 or maybe here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: Implementing from scratch is a large task because you need to implement your own user Identity system before you could even get into google.  Ms has a good guide that will enable google auth in a project that uses Individual accounts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/

Comment: I looked into the code that comes with MVC template and even tried porting that over to my non mvc web api project but I don't know what pieces are involved. All documentation online points to using the template. I have built the web abi and placed the authorize attribute on the functions that need authentication. From here I am lost as to how to incorporate google authentication. I tried writing some code for oauth, created google API client key and client secret. I was even able to get a token back inside postman using, but when I send post request to my authorize method I get a 404.

Comment: At this point you would really need to provide some code.  The only other thing I could suggest is put a page break on controller that allows all access and check the user object are they authenticated?  Also check their claims do they have the claims required to access the resource?

Comment: See update please. I am only trying to get the MVC Web API external auth sample to work.